# Extract String Between Two Characters in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I was hoping to get some help extracting a portion of a string between two characters in Power Automate. I've tried various iterations of substring and trim but I just can't seem to nail it.

One of our flows is sent a telephone number country code that comes through like this: `United States (+1)`. I want to store only the `+1` in our list so need to figure out how to get the value between left and right parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to skin this cat ...!  If that's the string your dealing with then this will work but depending on the complexity, it won't work for all cases.  You'd have to provide examples of other scenarios if this is a problem ...

[image: Flow]

The expression in the second step is ...

```
replace(split(variables('Text'), '(')[1], ')', '')
```

... like I said, it may not work for everything but will work for the example you provided.

[image: Result]